# ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got Python object

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, crf

I am testing an open-source code but I keep running into this error. I am passing a crf model into cross_val_predict and that's where the error starts. Pystruct is being used for the crf model. The crf model is built from sparse matrices which I think is causing the problem but I am not entirely sure.

This is the code:

```
def evaluate_dataset(config):
    # Parameters
    
    folds = config['folds']
    
    results = {}
    
    crf = config['clf']
    sample_size = config['sample_size'] if 'sample_size' in config else None
    
    paths = list(Path(config['dir']).iterdir())
    preprocessor = SectionPreprocess(ground_truth=True)
    paths, X, y = preprocessor.preprocess(paths, sample_size=sample_size)

    # Dataset information
    
    results['num_binaries'] = len(y)
    results['avg_code_fraction'] = np.mean([np.mean(yy) for yy in y])
    results['params'] = crf.get_params()
    
    # Cross-validation
    # logreg = LogisticRegression()
    results['cv_folds'] = folds

    start = time.time()
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(crf, X, y, cv=folds, n_jobs=1)
    end = time.time()
    results['cv_time'] = (end - start) / folds
    
    values = [
        (metrics.accuracy_score(true, pred),) + metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support(true, pred, average='binary')
        for (true, pred) in zip(y, y_pred)
    ]
    accuracy, precision, recall, f1, _ = zip(*values)
    
    results['cv_metrics'] = {
        'accuracy': (np.mean(accuracy), np.std(accuracy)),
        'precision': (np.mean(precision), np.std(precision)),
        'recall': (np.mean(recall), np.std(recall)),
        'f1': (np.mean(f1), np.std(f1)),
    }
    
    return results

evaluation_folder = Path('evaluation')
evaluation_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
for (name, config) in configurations.items():
    print(config)
    %time results = evaluate_dataset(config)
    print("## " + name)
    print(results)
    print('')
    
    file_path = evaluation_folder / (name + '.json')
    with file_path.open('w') as f:
        json.dump(results, f)
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 

 in evaluate_dataset(config)
     24 
     25     start = time.time()
---> 26     y_pred = cross_val_predict(crf, X, y, cv=folds, n_jobs=1)
     27     end = time.time()
     28     results['cv_time'] = (end - start) / folds

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, groups, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, method)
    399     prediction_blocks = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_predict)(
    400         clone(estimator), X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
--> 401         for train, test in cv_iter)
    402 
    403     # Concatenate the predictions

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    606                 return False
    607             else:
--> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    609                 return True
    610 

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    572         self._jobs.append(job)
    573 

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    110         if callback:
    111             callback(result)

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    325         # arguments in memory
--> 326         self.results = batch()
    327 
    328     def get(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in (.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_predict(estimator, X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
    472         estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    473     else:
--> 474         estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    475     func = getattr(estimator, method)
    476     predictions = func(X_test)

~/Google Drive (gdk244@nyu.edu)/MoMa Lab /CRF/code_section_identification/crf_models/CRFModel.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
     74             verbose=self.verbose
     75         )
---> 76         self._ssvm.fit(X, y)
     77 
     78         return self

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystruct/learners/frankwolfe_ssvm.py in fit(self, X, Y, constraints, initialize)
    295                 self._frank_wolfe_batch(X, Y)
    296             else:
--> 297                 self._frank_wolfe_bc(X, Y)
    298         except KeyboardInterrupt:
    299             pass

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystruct/learners/frankwolfe_ssvm.py in _frank_wolfe_bc(self, X, Y)
    220                 i = perm[j]
    221                 x, y = X[i], Y[i]
--> 222                 y_hat, delta_joint_feature, slack, loss = find_constraint(self.model, x, y, w)
    223                 # ws and ls
    224                 ws = delta_joint_feature * self.C

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystruct/utils/inference.py in find_constraint(model, x, y, w, y_hat, relaxed, compute_difference)
     63 
     64     if y_hat is None:
---> 65         y_hat = model.loss_augmented_inference(x, y, w, relaxed=relaxed)
     66     joint_feature = model.joint_feature
     67     if getattr(model, 'rescale_C', False):

~/.pyenv/versions/pythonvenv3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystruct/models/crf.py in loss_augmented_inference(self, x, y, w, relaxed, return_energy)
    104         pairwise_potentials = self._get_pairwise_potentials(x, w)
    105         edges = self._get_edges(x)
--> 106         loss_augment_unaries(unary_potentials, np.asarray(y), self.class_weight)
    107 
    108         return inference_dispatch(unary_potentials, pairwise_potentials, edges,

utils.pyx in utils.loss_augment_unaries (src/utils.c:5132)()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got Python object
```

Comment: You can't simply pass a scipy sparse matrix to a numpy function that expects a dense numpy array.

Comment: `np.asarray(y)` will produce an object dtype array is `y` is a scipy sparse matrix.  The correct conversion to array is `y.toarray()` or `y.A` for short.

Comment: That's within the pystruct module, how can I change this?

Comment: I don't know where your code ends and the extra module(s) start.  But in general if the other modules don't explicitly say they accept sparse matrices, don't pass those.  Some `sklearn` code is ok with sparse, and says so in the docs.

Comment: Resolved this by installing a patch that allows pystruct to work with parse matrices.
https://github.com/pystruct/pystruct/pull/4/files

Installed using: 
pip wheel -w dependencies git+https://github.com/pystruct/pystruct.git@refs/pull/4/merge#egg=pystruct